# JavaScript differences beetween new Regex('regex', 'flags') and /regex/flags

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var a = 'toto titi (should be removed) 5'.replace(/\(.*\)|\[.*\]|[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]|tata|tutu|tyty/gi, '!$!');
var b = 'toto titi (should be removed) 5'.replace(new RegExp('\(.*\)|\[.*\]|[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]|tata|tutu|tyty', 'gi'), '!$!');
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

I want to replace by space every char which is not a number or a letter or a space and chars which are beetween () and []. 
I have 2 same sentences, and I use the same pattern. The only one difference is that I use the `/regex/flags` syntax for `var a` and the object syntax `new Regex('regex','flags')` for `var b`.

However the result is not the same for a and for b.

Output is :

```
toto titi !$! 5 //a (it's the expected result)
!$!!$!          //b
```

I don't understand why. Could you explain me ?
I have to use the object syntax because I need to build my regex with variables.

Comment: You need to double escape when using a Regexp constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In strings, a backslash (`\`) is used for escaping special characters, such as in `\\`, `\'`, `\"`. In a regex, backslashes are also used for escaping, such as a literal `\(` or `\.`.

This means that when creating a regex from a string, you need to escape backslashes in the string as well. So you would do:

```
new RegExp('\\(.*\\)|\\[.*\\]|[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]|tata|tutu|tyty', 'gi')
```

Using this it gives the expected result.